# logrotate include more similar directories

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, logrotate

I'm using logrotate for my apache access/error logs. I have many subdomains with the same configuration.

```
/basedir/www/mysubdomain/logs
```

So I programmed my logrorate with

```
/basedir/www/*/logs/*.log {
    Blabla daily do stuff
}
```

I though it would include all my subdomains, but it's not working.
Would be pleased for any help.

Comment: I think, this should work in log path: `/basedir/www/*/logs/*.log`.

Comment: Can you paste here your logrotate configuration ? what happens if you execute manually `logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf` ?

Comment: I wrote a mistake I mean, I have /basedir/www/*/logs/*.log and it's not working. the editor interpret this as cursive

Comment: `rotating log /basedir/www/subdomain/logs/error.log, log->rotateCount is 30
dateext suffix '-20180524'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
glob finding old rotated logs failed`

this is an extract from the log of logrotate -f it seams it trying to rotate but it can't